# ASP.NET MVC5 - unwanted field created after update database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a 'one to many' relation between the classes 'ApplicationUser' and one recently created called 'Issue'.

So, in **Models / IdentityModels.cs / ApplicationUser** i added this property:

```
public ICollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
```

And **Issue.cs** has this code:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
    public class Issue
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser Courier { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser Customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm using automatic migrations. So, after building and running 'update-database', the **Issues table** was created with these fields:

1. Id
2. ApplicationUser_Id
3. CourierId
4. CustomerId

My question is **why was the field 'ApplicationUser_Id ' created**  and how can i prevent it?

Comment: What's the intent of the added property? What it is supposed to contain - issues where the user is `Courier` or where it is `Customer`?

Comment: Have you using Code First migration schema? Probably you need to set `KeyAttribute` on your PK field to keep defined primary key and create table relationships before executing migration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that EF thinks you actually want three one-to-many relationships between Issue and ApplicationUser:

- one for `ICollection<Issue> Issues` on `ApplicationUser` (ApplicationUser_Id)
- one for `ApplicationUser Courier` on `Issue` (CourierId)
- one for `ApplicationUser Customer` on `Issue` (CustomerId)

(Note that EF allows to define relationships from either side.)

If you want that `ApplicationUser.Issues` contains all Issues of this User, whether he is a Courier or Customer, you will need the additional **ApplicationUser_Id** key. Configuring EF so that this works will be quite a pain.

Maybe a simpler solution will do: introduce two collections on `ApplicationUser`.

```
public ICollection<Issue> CourierIssues { get; set; }
public ICollection<Issue> CustomerIssues { get; set; }
```

And then configure the backlinks in the ModelBuilder using the fluent API to eliminate the **ApplicationUser_Id** key:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(au => au.CourierIssues).WithOptional(i => i.Courier);
 modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(au => au.CustomerIssues).WithOptional(i => i.Customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two foreign keys to `ApplicationUser`, `Courier` and `Customer`, but only one collection referencing `Issue` on `ApplicationUser`. EF has no way of know which foreign key it should line up with, so it just created a new one. To handle this properly, you need to utilize fluent config:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    ...

    public class Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {
        HasMany(m => m.Issues).WithRequired(m => m.Customer);
    }
}
```

Then, in your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUser.Mapping());
}
```

The problem here of course, is that you are likely wanting to track collections for both the `Customer` and `Courier` collections. For that, you need *two* collections:

```
public virtual ICollection<Issue> CustomerIssues { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Issue> CourierIssues { get; set; }
```

Then, the following fluent config:

```
HasMany(m => m.CustomerIssues).WithRequired(m => m.Customer);
HasMany(m => m.CourierIssues).WithRequired(m => m.Courier);
```